# Android Webview access denied

Tags: android

On Android 9 (Api 29) am trying to load a url and i get the error "The webpage at url could not be loaded because: net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED".

I have internet the internet permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml` files

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

From logcat, i can see the the following error as well :

`E/chromium: [ERROR:socket_posix.cc(94)] CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Operation not permitted (1)`

My code is as follows :

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadUrl("https://andela.com/alc/");
```

I later added the following code to get more detail :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        Log.d("TAG", error.getDescription().toString());
        // handler.proceed(); This line wont make a different on API 29, Webview still bank
    }
});
```

The Webview loads the url properly when using an emulator running API 25. Also tested on API 28 and it works fine. Only doesn't work on API 29.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the `<uses-permission>` element in the correct spot? It needs to be a child of the root `<manifest>` element, not a child of `<application>` or anything else.

Comment: @CommonsWare its at the top of <application></application> in the manifest file

Comment: I have absolutely the same problem. Yes, uses-permission is in the root of manifest, and the same line i see in logcat:
 (E/chromium: [ERROR:socket_posix.cc(94)] CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Operation not permitted (1))

Comment: Filed it as a bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137791350

Comment: I have a same problem. How to handle this problem?

Comment: I see exactly this too. If I then target api 26 or some such, the code works fine. What did they break in API 29? What do we have to do to make it happy?

Comment: @DinoFancellu For now am just running on API 25. There's now word on the issue i filed.

Comment: What happens when you add this code? - Do NOT use in production! Make sure this is the only time you call setWebViewClient. 
 > webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { @Override public void onReceivedSslError(WebView v, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError er) { handler.proceed(); } });

Answer (score 11):

just uninstall the app and once again install it.That work 100%

Answer (score 7):

In my case the web page becomes loading correctly (without `ERR_ACCESS_DENIED`) after changing `applicationId` in `build.gradle` (and run the app, of-course). After that you may return the old `applicationId`.

Comment: Thats very srange, after changing the `applicationId` it worked. But returning the old `applicationId` stops working again

Comment: It's not a solution. If I change `applicationId` I can't deploy it.

Comment: The solution has two steps. Step 1 - change your current applicationId (it can be some random id) and build the app. Step 2 - set your previous applicationId and build the app again. After that, your WebView should start working.

Comment: I am expierencing the same issue. But this issue is on one android device, on the other android device I do not have this problem. In my case changing `applicationId` fixes this but I can even just put app to background and not change `applicationId` and it still loads page (I think the same happens when we change `appplicationId` - just a new app is starting)

Answer (score 4):

This is broke in the latest "Q Android 10", change target frame work to "Pie- Android 9" which will work. Change by going to

> File > Project Structure
>
> Then on left > Modules > Compiler SK Version (change to Api 28)

Note: Install Android PIE if it not already or the option does not appear by going to Preferences  then > System Preference > Android SDK on left

Comment: Is there any word on why this broke and if it was an intended change in API level 29? Currently this breaks basically every plugin and SDK that uses a Webview.

Answer (score 4):

Targetting Android S+ will require you to provide file access permission if the html file is accessed from the device storage.
Just add the line below:

```
webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

This resolved the mentioned error for me.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the application from the emulator or phone completely and compile or install again. It should already work.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall application first and reinstall after inserting permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Do not just restart.

Answer (score -1):

Might be SSL cert throwing error, try this:

```java
// Ignoring SSL certificate errors

@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError er) {
   handler.proceed();
}
```

You can try building your app with **[Android Smart WebView](https://github.com/mgks/Android-SmartWebView)** framework, it can provide you more insight on what might be going on with your webpage.

Comment: Sorry if the question was not clear, am already proceeding, but the issue is that on API 29, it doesnt matter whether  you add `handler.proceed()`, web page is still blank